# How to create an Oracle Procedure which includes a Subquery for an SQL Insert Into clause?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a problem to declare an Database Procedure, which includes an SQL Insert Into Statement with a subquery. I use an Oracle database. I get an errormessage, that tells me the **From keyword was not found where expected (ORA-00923)**. Could somebody explain me, how I create this syntax error in the following example ?

```
DECLARE

    PROCEDURE myProcedure(schema in varchar2) AS
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || schema || '.myTable(column_1, column_2, column_3)
            (
              SELECT extern_column_1,
                     extern_column_2,
                     extern_column 3
              FROM ' || schema || '.myExternTable
            )';
        END;

BEGINN

    FOR S IN (SELECT * FROM ROOT_SCHEMA.myTableWithSchema)
      LOOP
        myProcedure(S.mySchemata);
      END LOOP
      COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Is there a problem with the sign **'** in this code?. Thanks for helping me !

Comment: `BEGIN` instead of `BEGINN`. `'INSERT INTO '` instead of  `'INSERT INTO'`.

Comment: sorry, I have corrected this mistake. It was my mistake during opening this post. In my real code it stands the keyword beginn. The secound mistake istn´t exist in my real code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the opening and closing braces around the select and use the below

```
         PROCEDURE myProcedure(p_schema in varchar2) AS
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || p_schema || '.myTable(column_1, column_2, column_3)
                  SELECT extern_column_1,
                         extern_column_2,
                         extern_column 3
                  FROM ' || p_schema ||'.myExternTable
                ';
            END;
```

Comment: sorry, but this fix doesn´t work. I get the same error message.

Comment: i have included a space after INTO try now

Comment: can you name the parameter schema as p_schema

Comment: i did the same insert in plsql and it is working fine,can you post the actual skeleton of the SELECT QUERY

Comment: I have found the mistake. You are right with your answers. Instaed of " FROM ' || schema || '.myExternTable" I have written "FROM' || schema || '.myExternTable" in my real code. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to put the constructed statement into one variable. It gives flexibility to print the statement and check for syntactically correctness and also with re-using the code to execute the same statement with different inputs.

Note :- my opinion is purely based only on the use case described in the question.

```
DECLARE
   PROCEDURE myprocedure(SCHEMA IN VARCHAR2) AS
      lo_statement VARCHAR2(32767);
   BEGIN
      lo_statement := 'INSERT INTO ' || SCHEMA || '.myTable(column_1, column_2, column_3)
            (
              SELECT extern_column_1,
                     extern_column_2,
                     extern_column_3
              FROM ' || SCHEMA || '.myExternTable
            )';
      --dbms_output.put_line(lo_statement); 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lo_statement;
   END;
BEGIN
   FOR s IN (SELECT * FROM root_schema.mytablewithschema)
   LOOP
      myprocedure(s.myschemata);   
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```